# What to do after a "rm -R /*"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, rm

I was working on my website under root and I commit the worst thing that a linux user can do : `rm -R /*` instead of `rm -R ./*`.
I've stopped the process when I saw that it was taking too long...
I manage to reinstall lubuntu with an usb key, is this a good idea or are there other ways to reverse this big mistake ?

Thanks to any answer

Comment: I hate to say it, given the severity of your type-o. I feel for ya man. But this question is best suited for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Ok... Thanks anymay... I'll try to reinstall lubuntu via a USB key

Comment: there's nothing to do, since `nothing` is the only thing you will have after a rm -R /* :D

Comment: Ok, I've reinstalled lubuntu and now if someone has the trick to avoid the deadly command, post it

Comment: the classic way to avoid accidental `rm /` is: ensure that you never have more access than is necessary. find ways to work without sudo / root. macOS goes a little further: System Integrity Protection ensures that even as root, the user lacks the privilege to delete system files.

consider describing your entire system using Docker containers; it lets you create reproducible, sandboxed subsystems. your machine's only responsibility would be to start a Docker daemon. then with non-root privileges: you can start up Docker containers (e.g. for a webserver service or database service).

Comment: I've taken the habit of always executing an `ls` instead of `rm` when it could be destructive. After checking the output, I just have two chars to replace in the previous command... small price to pay!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: depends on the filesystem and on how `rm` is implemented. It's possible that rm merely unlinks the file; the inode (marked "deleted") and data may still remain. And even if the inode is hard-deleted, the data may remain. But in either case: there is a risk that your actions since that time have already written data over your old data or over the location of the soft-deleted inode. This can happen even with temporary files, or file descriptors (such as for sockets or processes) or pagefile [well, unless that thing has its own partition].

I wouldn't recommend trying to relink soft-deleted inodes, or infer from your data how to reconstruct hard-deleted inodes. Sure, maybe for irreplaceable memories this would be worth it (take the drive to a data forensics specialist), but there's near-guaranteed corruption *somewhere* on the disk. I would certainly not attempt to run a production system off a disk recovered like that.

I recommend one of the following:

- restoring from your regularly-scheduled backup
- wiping everything and starting again (you have all your website files stored under source control and stored remotely, right?)
- redeploying your Docker image (this *was* an immutable deployment, right?)

Comment: Well, it's hard for me because I had no backups and I corrupt the OS, I wipped everything and I started again, if someone is interested to follow the reconstruction of the hole server : https://teamiskog.ddns.net

Comment: I've described [some recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808321/what-to-do-after-a-rm-r/44808580#comment76597652_44808321) in a reply to your similar comment above